# roslocate info turtlebot | rosws merge -

Tags: ros, turtlebot, rosws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well ... in guide : http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays
I try to do this command:

roslocate info turtlebot | rosws merge -

But I receive this error:

```
File "/usr/bin/rosws", line 64, in <module>
  sys.exit(rosinstall.rosws_cli.rosws_main(sys.argv))
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosinstall/rosws_cli.py", line 551, in rosws_main    
 return ws_commands[command](workspace, args)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosinstall/rosws_cli.py", line 259, in cmd_merge
  config=config)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosinstall/multiproject_cli.py", line 612, in prompt_merge
extra_verbose))
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosinstall/multiproject_cli.py", line 512, in _get_element_diff
  diff = string_diff(old_val, new_val)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosinstall/common.py", line 139, in string_diff
  str1 = str1.ljust(len(str2))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ljust'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41785/roslocate-info-turtlebot-%7C-rosws-merge--/) by [leo_eng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3047/leo_eng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-08-18

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leo_eng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3047/leo_eng/) on 2012-08-18**:
I receive : - hg:
local-name: turtlebot
meta:
repo-name: turtlebot-ros-pkg
uri: https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot
version: default
What is the result in this case? And I have to put the result in "fuerte_workspace"?

**Comment by [leo_eng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3047/leo_eng/) on 2012-08-18**:
I receive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a bug, thanks for reporting it. I filed it here:
https://kforge.ros.org/vcstools/trac/ticket/65
will investigate

In the meantime, you can just call:

```
roslocate info turtlebot
```

and add the result to the .rosinstall file in your workspace

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3